# How can I quickly check number of groups in my domain?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Probably this is simplistic question but it seems that off the top of my head I have no idea how to do this. How can I get number of groups in my domain? In all domains within the forest? What is the easiest way to do it? I understand that that writing some script is an option but just checking if there is easier way to do this without reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skin this cat a few different ways.

From a domain member computer run the command `net group /domain | clip` and a list of all the Global and Universal Security Groups in the domain of the logged-on user. A `net localgroup /domain | clip` will give you all the Domain Local Security Groups. The legacy `net` command won't interact with the Global Catalog. In a single domain environment that's fine, but in a multi-domain environment you'll need to use other tools.

The `dsquery` tool can query the global catalog. Running the command `dsquery group forestroot -gc -limit 0 | clip` will return all the Security Groups from all domains in the forest. Unlike the `net` command, the `dsquery` command is typically only available on servers, making it slightly more inconvenient to run.

You could use an LDAP query tool to perform a subtree query of the forest root of the Global Catalog looking for objects with an `objectCategory` set to `group` as another viable solution.